# Android See bitmap pixel values

Tags: android, arrays, pixel, android-bitmap

I'm on a image processing study. I've read and researched about bitmaps, pixels and arrays. I want to know the pixel values of the image. My plan is to convert the bitmap to an array and save it as a text file. Is there any other way to see the whole array of pixel values of an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to convert an image to text. It is actually called a byte array. You can do this like so:

```
        // Convert bitmap to byte array
        Bitmap bitmap = bitmapImage;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos);
        byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();
```

You can also just take the byte array and then save the actual values instead of turning it into an image file. To turn the byte array into a file, do this:

```
        // Create a file to write bitmap data
        File f = new File(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir(), "image.png");
        f.createNewFile();

        // INSERT ABOVE CODE HERE (BITMAP TO BYTE ARRAY CONVERSION)

        // Write the bytes in file
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fos.write(bitmapdata);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
```

Comment: Thanks, I also have read about byte array. im gonna try that soon enough. Again thanks!

Comment: I have a question AkashBhave, Is the FILE that will be written can be seen on External storage? Is it .TXT? Thanks

Comment: The file that is created is saved to the internal storage in a folder that a user cannot read, *only the app*. Also, the file that is saved is a .PNG file, since that was the name I gave it during association.

Comment: Okay... Now I got what you are doing. This is what i want to do. I want to check the pixel value of the image. For example, if the image has size (row = 5, col =3) then the the text file will have {12345, 12345, 12345} 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 being the pixel values... Thanks...

Comment: Oh, sorry for the misunderstanding. What exactly do you mean by pixel value? Do you mean the color of the pixel?

Comment: I want to know the "value" of the pixel. If it's byte array, then values will only range from [-127, 127]. Later I will manipulate the elements in the array...